# javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed

Tags: java, exception, ejb, jndi, naming

Am trying this since yesterday night, we are integrating two different builds but still failing to get all the session bean lookups to work. The ProjectBeanRemote is located in the project.beans package. The lookup with "java:global/JavaFinalProjectS-ejb ... " is working with some beans but some are not being looked up. The persistance unit being used is EclipseLink and the name is JavaFinalProjectS-ejbPU. Both the ways of the lookup are throwing a naming exception.

```
       public class ControlServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP
 * <code>GET</code> and
 * <code>POST</code> methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /*
         * TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code.
         */
        HttpSession sessObj=request.getSession();
        if(null==sessObj.getAttribute("proBeaSesObj"))
        {
            InitialContext initContObj=new InitialContext();
            Object initObj=initContObj.lookup("java:global/JavaFinalProjectS-ejb/ProjectBean");
            ProjectBeanRemote proBeaObj=(ProjectBeanRemote)
                    initContObj.lookup(ProjectBeanRemote.class.getName());
            sessObj.setAttribute("proBeaSesObj", proBeaObj);
            this.sendRequestForward(proBeaObj, request, response, out,sessObj);
        }
        else
        {
            ProjectBeanRemote proBeaObj=(ProjectBeanRemote)sessObj.getAttribute("proBeaSesObj");
            this.sendRequestForward(proBeaObj, request, response, out,sessObj);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception g)
    {
        g.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

This is the stackTrace

```
                SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/JavaFinalProjectS-ejb/ProjectBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ProjectBean not found]
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at project.servlets.ControlServlet.processRequest(ControlServlet.java:47)
at project.servlets.ControlServlet.doPost(ControlServlet.java:96)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
             Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ProjectBean not found
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
... 32 more

SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
SEVERE:     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
SEVERE:     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
SEVERE:     at project.servlets.ControlServlet.processRequest(ControlServlet.java:47)
SEVERE:     at project.servlets.ControlServlet.doPost(ControlServlet.java:96)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
SEVERE: Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ProjectBean not found
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
SEVERE:     ... 32 more
```

Any help is welcome, have tried lots of things with the lookup but still can't get it all to work.